# How can we differentiate between adjectives and past participles?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning, adjectives, adjective-phrases

How can we differentiate between adjectives and past participles?

For example if we say:

> The project is excited

*excited* in this example would be the adjective, but:

> The project excited us

*excited* here would be the past participle.

So, my question is:
**How can I differentiate between past participles and the adjectives in a sentence?**

Comment: By the way, "The project is excited" is grammatical, but nonsensical.  Projects don't get excited—people do. The proper way to rephrase the first example:  "The project was exciting."

Comment: also "the project excited us" is not past participle.

Answer (score 1):

The word *excited* in

> The project excited us

is not a past participle, but past tense.  You can tell here because *project* is the subject and *excited* is *project's* verb.

Some irregular verbs have distinct forms for past participle as opposed to past tense.

> Take the half eaten food and throw it away
>
> I don't care what you do with the broken things, just throw them out.

Anyway, a past participle is part of a verb phrase or used as a modifier.

> I have been known to go there from time to time.
>
> The excited dog jumped all over our guests.
>
> It was laid on the floor.
>
> The interested parties should convene tomorrow.

It can get complicated when phrases are involved instead of words.

> The common known thing between them did not affect their relationship.
>
> Her misspoken words struck me like a sledgehammer.

But really, unless the past participle does not follow a form of *to have* or *to be*, you can pretty much just treat it like an adjective.